# Need help with json parsing

Tags: java, json

I'm getting this json string info from the server :

```
{"members":[["sd2840d","Johny"],["jkld341","Marry"]]}
```

So I store in in variable :

```
js = "{\"members\":[[\"sd2840d\",\"Johny\"],[\"jkld341\",\"Marry\"]]}";
```

and create json object

```
json = new JSONObject(js);
```

Naturally I have many occurences of members, each member has something like identifier `sd2840d` and name `Johny` both strings, how can I create for loop or foreach loop that will print out .. this is identifier `sd2840d` and this is name `Johny`, so on for Marry etc. tnx

Comment: This question is a bit ambiguous. Are you asking this in Java or Javascript perspective? Using what language would you like to loop and print the JSON?

Comment: @BalusC its tagged in java, I'm interested in how can it be done in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(
    "{\"members\":[[\"sd2840d\",\"Johny\"],[\"jkld341\",\"Marry\"]]}");

JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("members");

for (int idx = 0; idx != array.length(); idx++) {
  JSONArray array2 = array.getJSONArray(idx);
  System.out.println(array2.getString(0));
  System.out.println(array2.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: @Jim Blackler thank you , I get this error msg :

`Error: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1`

Comment: Funny, are you using 'org.json.JSONObject'?

Comment: @Jim Blackler Yes and array `import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;`

Comment: This error is on the first line? I have run this code and it does work for me.

Comment: what package are you using for this JSONObject?